# C - nested for loop patern

Tags: c, for-loop

how to get output like flipped floyds triangle? and how's the best way to solve it?

Example :

```
5555
_555
__55
___5
```

note : _ is a space

already tried lot of code but still I cant get output like that.

one of my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a,b,c,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(a=1;a<=n;a++) {
        for(b=n;b>=a;b--) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(c=1;c<=a;c++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code..,

Comment: Show _already tried lot of code_

Comment: @BLUEPIXY He tried so many code that all the code can not be placed in the question. There is no enough room.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh


#include<stdio.h>

int main () {

 int a,b,c,n;

 scanf("%d",&n);

 for(a=1;a<=n;a++) {

  for(b=n;b>=a;b--) {

   printf(" ");

  }

  for(c=1;c<=a;c++) {

   printf("*");

  }

 printf("\n");

 }

}

but this code output is upside-down version of what i want

Comment: not in a comment, in the question itself. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: welp, sorry bro I'm new on this page @SouravGhosh

Comment: @soloemollyn Well, welcome!! I personally prefer a bit more formal addressing while communicating.

Comment: `for(a=1;a<=n;a++) {` --> `for(a=n;a>=1;a--) {`

Comment: @NiallCosgrove It is not good to return edit to _example_. Extra line breaks in the output example misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way... but the code is similar to the one posted by you.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (a = n; a > 0; a--)
    {
        for (b = n; b >= a; b--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (c = 1; c <= a; c++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

In the original post you first for loop was

```
for(a=1;a<=n;a++)
```

which meant the 2nd for loop would print n*space and the 3rd for loop would print 1 star.
By changing the first for loop to

```
for (a = n; a > 0; a--)
```

Everything gets inverted so first loop will print no space and last for loop n*stars.

Comment: so that it steals my credit card number? no, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a joke;)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int n = 5555;

    while (n)
    {
        printf("%5d\n", n);
        n /= 10;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as required.:)

```
 5555
  555
   55
    5
```

If to use loops then the program for example can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char c = '5';

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ");

        unsigned int n;

        if (scanf("%u", &n) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        putchar('\n');

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            unsigned int j = i + 1;
            printf("%*c", (int)j, c);
            while (j++ < n) putchar(c);
            putchar('\n');
        }

        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

5555555555
 555555555
  55555555
   5555555
    555555
     55555
      5555
       555
        55
         5

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

The inner while loop can be substituted for the for loop

```
for ( ; j < n; j++ )
```

Comment: sure things I'm gonna write it down like that if my lecture didn't told me to do it on nested for loop XD